# How to customize login page open edx

Tags: openedx

is possible to customize the style of login page using indigo theme? https://github.com/overhangio/tutor-indigo Just want to change the styles like background color and button color, and also want to add some text and images in login page [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVqpu.png)

I can change the styles of other page using this file directory tutorindigo/templates/indigo/lms/static/sass/
but I want to override or change the styles the login page

Please give me advice of how to customize the login page
Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can do this. Since the login page is built using MFE you can follow this approach.
Make changes in the https://github.com/openedx/brand-openedx package and install it in MFE. You can change everything related to style using this package.